# MariaDB REGEXP_REPLACE with semicolon in replace string throws error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For Youtube videos inside news articles I'm trying to replace all old `<object>` html tags (flash) to `<iframe>` tags. But there is a huge problem as the database throws a syntax error when I use semicolons (;) in the replace string. Even when I escape them, the error persists

```
UPDATE 
  `news_items` 
SET 
  `content` = REGEXP_REPLACE(content, 
                '(?sm)<object.*?width\="([0-9]+)".*?height\="([0-9]+)".*?value\="((http://|https://).*?)".*<\/object>', 
                '<iframe width="\\1" height="\\2" src="\\3" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen><\/iframe>')
WHERE 
  ID = 9551;
```

It happens at `allow="accelerometer;`.
How can I escape this?

Edit: I replaced the delimiter to `%%`, ran the query, and put `;` delimiter back, this worked

Comment: show the exact error you are seeing?  and what does `select version();` show?

Comment: works just fine for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=bd756798cdb83e484cb1dcfa398a07a4

Comment: It didn't work for me, But i now found out that it has something to do with the delimiter. I changed the delimiter to `%%` , then performed the query and then changed the delimiter back to `;` This works. (version is 10.4.21)

Comment: is this in a stored procedure declaration or something, not just a query you are running?

Comment: No, it's really just a query, I'm running it from the console . But it's solved by temporarily replacing the delimiter :)

Comment: I tested the query on MariaDB 10.5 and it worked. I suspect you ran into the common problem of mismatched quotes or similar quotes in the replace string data.

Comment: Try it on 10.4.21 the only solution for me was to temporarily change the delimiter symbol because it clashed with the ; in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, because the string in the query contains a character that clashes with the sql delimiter. I replaced the delimiter to `%%`, ran the query, and put `;` back as delimiter. This worked.